# Autoscaling Seldon Deployments based on GPU metric

Tags: gpu, autoscaling, seldon, seldon-core

Is it possible to autoscale Seldon Deployment based on GPU Metrics?

In official documentation (https://docs.seldon.io/projects/seldon-core/en/latest/examples/autoscaling_example.html), the prerequisite for autoscaling is to use metric-server, which doesn't have custom metrics (just cpu/memory).

I'm using Nvidia device plugin on AWS EKS cluster.